# How do I catkin-depend on the SDFormat library?

Tags: catkin, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a ROS-hydro catkinized package that depends on SDFormat library, but can't figure out how to get it to link properly to the SDFormat library.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5174/how-do-i-catkin-depend-on-the-sdformat-library?/) by [David Lu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/153/david-lu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 111 on 2013-12-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-12-30**:
Are you trying to build sdformat in a catkin workspace or just link to a system install of sdformat?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/153/david-lu/) on 2013-12-31**:
Specifically, I'm trying to get a package that uses the SDFormat library to build on the ROS build farm.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

SDFormat is not a catkin package; it is a plain cmake package. [Gazebo uses pkg-config](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/cmake/SearchForStuff.cmake#cl-71) to find sdformat and [explicitly links against the sdformat libraries](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/gazebo/common/CMakeLists.txt#cl-146) where necessary.

If you also want to build sdformat from source in a catkin workspace, you will need to add a package.xml file (see the [package_xml branch in sdformat](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat/src/package_xml/package.xml) for an example).

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-12-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Normally, you would [add a system dependency](http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/howto/system_library_dependencies.html) on **sdformat**, which *is* released with Hydro. Unfortunately, it does not seem to have been defined via **rosdep** yet. You should probably [contribute the missing definition](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html) to fix that problem.

Then, in your **package.xml**, add:

```
<build_depend>sdformat</build_depend>
<run_depend>sdformat</run_depend>
```

With **sdformat** installed, in your **CMakeLists.txt**, find the SDF system library:

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(SDF sdformat REQUIRED)
include_directories(include ${SDF_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Then your own code will need something like this to build with it:

```
add_executable(your_node ${YOUR_NODE_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(your_node
                      ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
                      ${SDF_LIBRARIES})
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/18/joq/) with karma: 113 on 2014-01-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2014-01-03**:
You actually need to search for sdformat: `pkg_check_modules(SDF sdformat REQUIRED)`. It's a quirk of Gazebo's cmake setup; we already had variables with prefix `SDF_` spread out, so we search for sdformat, but with variables named SDF. Sorry if that's a confusing example.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/18/joq/) on 2014-01-03**:
Thanks for the correction. Are the `SDF_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `SDF_LIBRARIES` variable names I had guessed correct?

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2014-01-06**:
Yes, I believe that [SDF_INCLUDE_DIRS](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/gazebo/CMakeLists.txt#cl-6) and [SDF_LIBRARIES](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/default/gazebo/common/CMakeLists.txt#cl-146) are correct.